# Should API calls be GET or POST?

Tags: php, api

I noticed that some APIs like the Twitter API use get methods for everything, so the parameters are passed in the URL like this:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=screenname
```

I have some questions and would appreciate comments or corrections:

1. I always thought that using GET is not a good idea, and that it's better to use POST.
2. The API I'm coding requires a key, and I don't think it's a good idea to send it in the URL. So, is it possible to mix both POST parameters and URL parameters?
3. Another problem is that I hear URLs have a max length, so I guess that would make GET out of the way, or is there a workaround?
4. The only problem I'm seeing with POST (and which I'm guessing is why a site like twitter went with GET) is that the request can't be made directly from the browser. Correct me if I'm wrong on this.

---

**Updates: Thanks to everyone who's helping me brainstorm this. I have some updates to clarify some of the comments.**

1. When I was talking about not wanting to send the key in the URL, what I meant is that I don't want the key bookmarked if a user were to bookmark a call, not that I don't want the key exposed at all. So I guess from the answers that I could send it in the header field? Any other options?
2. I want to clarify that when I said POST requests `can't be made from the browser`, I should have said, `POST requests can't be made from the URL` as in `http://example.com/api/op.json?param=value`. Sorry, I misspoke, should have been clearer.
3. Re whether it's RESTful or not: I've done RESTful before with an MVC framework that took care of detecting the verbs and the URLs ended up looking like `example.com/entry/1`, or `example.com/entry/` and the HTTP verbs are what controlled the operation being performed (create, update, delete, list). I thought, in a practical sense, that RESTful was most useful for crud-like data (create entry, get entry, update entry, delete entry, show all entries). So if I don't need crud, do I need REST? My question: if a call simply gives input and returns output, does this API need to be RESTful? The URL doesn't look RESTful, so is there something else in the implementation that could make it RESTful?
4. As to the URL size, you commented `but if you're seriously concerned about it you probably should rethink your API. GET requests shouldn't be sending that much data to the server.` So I have this example: user wants to send a large file. On the server, I won't enter the file into the database or save it (so according to standards I'm not "posting" data), but maybe I'm (these are quickly thought examples, so please take them loosely):

- (a) reading the metadata of the file and returning it (should that be GET or POST), or
- (b) I'm reading the metadata and modifying the metada on the file and returning the modified file (should that be GET or POST).
- So this is an example of why I might need to send large data. The question is are (a) and (b) considered GET or POST operations? and this is why I was asking about the URL max length

Comment: Are you GETting some data from the server? Use `GET`. Are you sending (or "POSTing") data to the server? Use `POST`.

Comment: You can also pass the key in a header field.

Comment: @Anon your logic will break when both or none are performed.

Comment: @Eugene What exactly does a request which neither fetches nor modifies server state do? To what end would you include this in an API?

Comment: @Meagar simple command/control protocol. It doesn't need getting or posting info.

Comment: @Eugene How is that not modifying server state?

Comment: @meagar this is not getting or posting *data*. This is an API. But this is not about *data* as you call it.

Comment: @Casey @Ates Goral @Rian Schmits @meagar @Eugene Thanks for your answers and comments. I've made updates to the question to clarify some stuff.

Comment: I think you should at least mention that GET will usually be cached by the browser, so if the data for the same GET request updates, you will need a workaround. For example sending a random parameter.

Answer (score 31):

> 1. I always thought that using GET is not a good idea and that it's better to use POST.

Use GET for reading information, POST for writing information. GET requests shouldn't modify server-side state, while POST requests can safely do so. In general use GET for reads and POST for writes. Your API should probably use a mixture of both, depending on which each specific API call does.

> 2. The API I'm coding requires a key, and I don't think it's a good idea to send it in the URL. So is it possible to mix both POST parameters and URL parameters?

Sending data via POST doesn't add any level of security at all. GET requests are no less insecure than POST requests; they are identical. For transferring private data, use SSL.

You should ideally use an HTTP header like `Authorization` to transmit the key, as this is less likely to be logged by intermediaries, or to be emitted to 3rd party services like bug-trackers.

> 3. Another problem is that I hear URLs have a max length, so I guess that would make GET out of the way, or is there a workaround

There is no maximum URL length defined by the HTTP standard, though [some browsers](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) impose one. This probably doesn't matter when generating GET requests via JavaScript, but if you're seriously concerned about it you probably should rethink your API. GET requests shouldn't be sending that much data to the server.

> 4. The only problem I'm seeing with POST (and which I'm guessing is why a site like twitter went with GET) is that the request can't be made directly from the browser. Correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Your browser can generate POST requests just as easily as GET requests, it's simply harder to submit POST requests via the address bar.

Answer (score 3):

The more comprehensive answer is: Please read about [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) and HTTP verbs in general.

Here are some short answers to your questions:

> I always thought that using GET is not
>   a good idea and that it's better to
>   use POST.

It depends on what you're doing.

> The API I'm coding requires a key, and
>   I don't think it's a good idea to send
>   it in the URL. So is it possible to
>   mix both POST parameters and URL
>   parameters?

Yes, it is possible. However, there won't really a big security difference between sending it through the URL versus the request body.

> Another problem is that I hear URLs
>   have a max length, so I guess that
>   would make GET out of the way, or is
>   there a workaround

The "workaround" is to use other verbs like POST or PUT for transmitting large amounts of data.

> The only problem I'm seeing with POST
>   (and which I'm guessing is why a site
>   like twitter went with GET) is that
>   the request can't be made directly
>   from the browser. Correct me if I'm
>   wrong on this.

POST requests can be made directly from the browser through the use of a simple HTML `<form>` with `method="POST"`.

Comment: Use GET when transactioning "public data". always use POST when transactioning "private data".

Answer (score 2):

As Anon said, Get for retrieving data, post for making changes/sending data, which keeps you in line with the http standard.  AFAIK, you can't mix GET/POST params.  You can make a post request from a browser by a form, but not by entering a url info the address bar.  A key in the get string vs. the post string is not really much different.  If the request gets intercepted in transit, the key is compromised either way.  If you use a public/private key pair to encrypt the key, than you can resolve that issue.  And yes, GET string do have a max length, but so does post, albeit much larger and dependent on your server settings.

Answer (score 1):

From server point of view, it doesn't matter much what mechanism is used. The only meaningful difference on the server side is that GET requests are usually logged completely (with parameters), while the data of POST requests are usually not logged (but this is not a rule for custom servers, which can log or not log anything).

Moreover, in many cases you can use GET or POST and the server will handle both cases correctly and transparently. Mixing is also possible, and most servers will handle in transparently as well.

GET requests are easier to debug (for web developers), and maybe this was the main reason to use them. I can also think of GET requests to be easier to handle and less resource- consuming (but this depends on how the code is written), cause in GET request everything is passed in header and CRLFCRLF is a request separator (with POST it's necessary to perform additional parsing of the body).

URLs do have max. length (4K to be a common limit, but not mandatory), yes. Some proxies and some servers (and maybe some clients) might be unable to handle larger URLs or have an artificial restriction (to prevent attacks).

I am not sure I understood your idea about "request can't be made directly from the browser". When you fill a web form in browser, it's POSTed to the server (unless JavaScript or AJAX is employed, cause using them you can have a GET request).

Comment: This is not true, and has not been true for many years. The HTTP verb matters greatly for RESTful APIs which are becoming the norm.

Comment: @Meagar did you ever implement a web server? Or even a client? RESTful APIs are higher level, than HTTP itself.

Comment: @Eugene The question was specifically about web-based APIs like Twitter. I'm pretty sure they sit on top of the web server.

Comment: @meagar read again. The question only says "some APIs use GET for everything". It doesn't say a word about RESTful or anything else as specific. Moreover, the questions are *generic* and about HTTP protocol itself.

Comment: @Eugene And the HTTP protocol provides different verbs for a reason. They matter.

Comment: @meagar They matter on *application* level, not from technical point of view. You just don't seem to understand how HTTP and HTTP servers in particular work internally.

Comment: @Eugene I have implemented both HTTP servers and clients and don't see a problem with @meagar's reasoning. And I don't see a relevance between implementation experience and knowledge about a given protocol. And actually, HTTP was meant to be "RESTful" from the get-go, but rapid abuse of the protocol led us to the abundantly RESTless Web we have today.

Comment: @Eugene APIs exist on the application level. We are talking about APIs, not web servers.

Comment: @meagar who "you"? That was not specified in the question. Moreover, the questions were about technical side: about limit of the URL length, about mixing parameters (pure technical things etc).

Comment: @Ates looks you didn't understand what you were implementing. RESTful APIs were invented as an extension on top of HTTP years later.

Comment: @Eugene What does implementing an HTTP server/client have anything to do with REST? It's the application that runs on the server and the application that uses the client that count.

Comment: @Eugene You're the only person *not* talking about APIs. The question is titled **"Should API calls be GET or POST"**; OP specifically asked about the Twitter API; the question specifically mentions **"The API I'm coding"**; the question is tagged with **PHP** and **API**. We are inarguably talking about APIs in this question.

Comment: @Meagar I don't know who "we" are - I was the first to post the answer. And API != REST. I know most here are just REST-kiddies, but this doesn't forgive their ignorance of HTTP basics.

Comment: You're forgetting about idempotence.

Answer (score 0):

Why not support both? It's the most flexible. I have only written one API (multiple versions), and making it support both GET and POST for all variables has come in handy both when implementing the client and debugging. It supports mixing and matching GET and POST. Use $_REQUEST and be done.